# AngularJS: Add and Edit List Items Using Same Input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to edit list items in the same input field I use for adding items.

Have a look at

http://jsbin.com/retadexu/188/edit

and

http://jsbin.com/retadexu/192/edit

The first example works, but I have to assign the temporary object's .name property to the list object:

```
$scope.currentItem.name = $scope.newToDo.name;
```

The second, where I assign the whole object, doesn't work:

```
$scope.currentItem = $scope.newToDo;
```

So if I had more than just the "name" property, do I really have to assign all values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of keeping track of the current by the object, keep track of the index in the array of that item.

```
$scope.saveTodo = function(todo) {
  if ($scope.editMode) {
    $scope.currentItem = $scope.newToDo;
    $scope.todos[$scope.currentItemIndex] = $scope.newToDo;
    $scope.editMode = false;
  } else {
    $scope.todos.push($scope.newToDo);
  }
  $scope.newToDo = "";
};

$scope.editTodo = function(todo) {
  $scope.editMode = true;
  $scope.newToDo = angular.copy(todo);
  $scope.currentItemIndex = $scope.todos.indexOf(todo);
};
```

I also moved the text of the button into the markup rather than the controller (personal preference)

```
<button ng-click="saveTodo(todo)">{{editMode ? 'Edit' : 'Add'}}</button>
```

See it working in this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/TsfFOgDCNXuHm578l7vJ?p=preview)

Comment: I also renamed the `addTodo` function to be `saveTodo` as it serves both purposes (add/edit)